# Change datatype in a query based on mapping table bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a mapping table which contains column names and corresponding data types. In my main query, all the columns are formatted as strings, is there a way to iterate through the columns and cast the data types in each column to their corresponding tables in the mapping table?

I have tried using FOR loops but it doesn't produce the desired result